# Get object from an array of dictionaries with a specific key value pair?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

So if I have a dictionary like the following:

```
{
 "banners": [
   {
     "imageUrl": "www.google.com",
     "destination": "home",
     "position": 1
   },
   {
     "imageUrl": "www.reddit.com",
     "destination": "work",
     "position": 2
   },
   {
     "imageUrl": "www.imgur.com",
     "destination": "play",
     "position": 3
   }
 ]
}
```

is there a way for me to say, "Get me the dictionary object where the value for the key 'position' = 3 without using a for loop?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that _someone_ has to look at all the dictionaries in the array until they find that one, even if the loop isn't visibly and directly in your code. So the notion "without using a for loop" is kind of silly. It is impossible for some magic power to go _directly_ to the right dictionary.

Comment: @matt I understand. I was just wondering if there was a nice factory method that already existed that looked cleaner that I could learn about that would also help in more advanced cases.

Answer (score 4):

Let's think about it. Oooh, there are a lot of ways! It's amazing what looking for just a moment at the documentation will tell you.

What you have as the value of the `banners` key is an array of dictionaries. So what you are looking for is an NSArray method. An NSArray method such as `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`!

So you can write an NSPredicate that describes `position` as being equal to `3`, and you'll get back an NSArray of all the dictionaries where that is true (in this case, an array of one dictionary).

Oh, here's another possibility: `indexOfObjectPassingTest:`. With this, you supply a block that specifies that the dictionary's `position` is `3`, and you'll get back the index of that dictionary within this array (namely 2 in this case).

I could go on and on, but wouldn't it be better for you to learn to read the documentation for yourself? [Here it is](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray?language=objc).